# How to do regex-replace in a file using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Based on this example:

> ```
> - lineinfile: dest=/opt/jboss-as/bin/standalone.conf regexp='^(.*)Xms(\d+)m(.*)$' line='\1Xms${xms}m\3' backrefs=yes
> ```

from [this documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html), it was tried to do a regex-replace in Ansible.

**Ansible version**

```
user@server:/home$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.1.0
```

**/path/to/file:**

```
helloworld
```

**Ansible snippets:**

```
- lineinfile:
  dest: /path/to/file
  regexp='^(hello)world$'
  line='\1030'
```

*attempt 2*

```
- lineinfile:
  dest: /path/to/file
  regexp='^(hello)world$'
  line="\1030"
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
hello030
```

**Current outcome:**

```
\1030
```

**Questions**

1. Why is the outcome `\1030` instead of `hello030`?
2. How to solve it?

Comment: what version of ansible are you running?

Comment: @PetterH `ansible 2.1.1.0`

Comment: The default is `backrefs: no`, your snips don't define it. Can you test with `backrefs: yes`? I don't have access just now to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why is the outcome \1030 instead of hello030?

The lineinfile module default is `backrefs: false`. Your `regexp='^(hello)world$'` matches the entire contents of *file*. Literal from `line='\1030'` replaces contents.

> How to solve it?

1. Turn on backrefs with `backrefs: true`
2. Use a named group in `line:`

A backref followed by numbers will not function as expected. You will need a named group instead. e.g. `\g<1>`

```
- name: Replace the world
  lineinfile:
    dest: file
    regexp: '^(hello)world$'
    line: '\g<1>030'
    backrefs: true
```

Answer (score -2):

I suppose it is because it matches whole \1030 (as 1030-th backref). Maybe try \1 030 first and you will see, if it is the reason.

Comment: `line='\1Xms${xms}m\3'` returns `\1Xms` as well